# How to remove the Window Commands From MahApps.Metro Template?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Metro template for WPF app. I want a Window which dont have any Window Command like minimize maximize and close. In normal WPf it can be done by WindowsStyle but how i can remove them in this template. And i also want to make the Window to be TopMost="True" and WindowState="Maximized". So all this settings are possible in this template ? Please advice ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to thange templates, just set some properties.

MetroWindow has properties:

```
<controls:MetroWindow ...

    Topmost="True" 
    WindowState="Maximized"

    ShowTitleBar="False" // Hide colored tile bar, title header and icon

    ShowCloseButton="False" 
    ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" 
    ShowMinButton="False"

    ShowWindowCommandsOnTop="False" // No window commands on top of flyouts
```

which will remove title bar (icon+color), and you can remove buttons too.

Comment: Every thing is working fine ... but topmost="true" is not working ? Any alternative ?

Comment: That a bug then in MahApps, submit it here: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues

Comment: Hey @Toplek Do you have any Idea about the Modern UI control how to remove the same. the Window commands like close ?

Comment: Sorry, I am only familiar with mahapps

Comment: ShowWindowCommandsOnTop="False" does not work for me.  I have ShowTitleBar="True".  Min, Max/Restore, and Close buttons are shown.  MahApps.Metro 0.13.1.0.

Comment: ShowWindowCommandsOnTop was replaced with the tetrad of LeftWindowCommandsOverlayBehavior, RightWindowCommandsOverlayBehavior, WindowButtonCommandsOverlayBehavior, and IconOverlayBehavior as of v. 0.14.